# Retry HTTP request from .NET with different proxy server

Tags: .net, http, proxy, polly, resiliency

I can issue HTTP requests through a proxy in a .NET app. There are a number of proxy servers I can use and sometimes one or more will go down. How can I have my app retry the HTTP request using a different proxy? I am open to any suggestion and have heard good things about Polly for adding resiliency.

Comment: What are you using to issue the requests?

Comment: System.Net.WebClient with the DownloadString method. I’m open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my use case, it turns out that I was better off without Polly.

```
public static string RequestWithProxies(string url, string[] proxies)
{
    var client = new WebClient
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password)
    };
    var result = String.Empty;

    foreach (var proxy in proxies)
    {
        client.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy);
        try
        {
            result = client.DownloadString(new Uri(url));
        }
        catch (Exception) { if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) break; }
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) throw new Exception($"Exhausted proxies: {String.Join(", ", proxies)}");
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you were to use Polly, maybe something like this:

```
public void CallGoogle()
{
    var proxyIndex = 0;

    var proxies = new List<IWebProxy>
    {
        new WebProxy("proxy1.test.com"),
        new WebProxy("proxy2.test.com"),
        new WebProxy("proxy3.test.com")
    };

    var policy = Policy
                 .Handle<Exception>()
                 .WaitAndRetry(new[]
                     {
                         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
                     }, (exception, timeSpan) => proxyIndex++);

    var client = new WebClient();

    policy.Execute(() =>
    {
        client.Proxy = proxies[proxyIndex];
        client.DownloadData(new Uri("https://www.google.com"));
    });
}
```

Comment: You really set me up for success here. Thank you very much.

Comment: How would you be able to access the proxyIndex if you create your policy in another class than the one that you consume it? Foe example in apsnet core, you crate your policy in the Startup and you inject it through the construction on your implementation.

Comment: Perhaps see the accepted answer, it's simply calling a function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer with Polly, but I don't like it as much as the answer without Polly or Polly with wait to retry.

```
public static string RequestWithProxies(string url, string[] proxies)
{
    var client = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password) };
    var result = String.Empty;
    var proxyIndex = 0;

    var policy = Policy.Handle<Exception>()
        .Retry(
            retryCount: proxies.Length,
            onRetry: (exception, _) => proxyIndex++);

    policy.Execute(() =>
    {
        if (proxyIndex >= proxies.Length) throw new Exception($"Exhausted proxies: {String.Join(", ", proxies)}");

        client.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxies[proxyIndex]);
        result = client.DownloadString(new Uri(url));
    });

    return result;
}
```