# Is it possible to change client's BaseAddress or client when using Polly ExecuteAsync after failed attempt?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient, polly, retrypolicy

I have implemented Polly in my solution using .net core 3.1 and Polly 7.2.0. I have created extensions for IServiceCollection and in my Startup file I am calling the extensions to configure and add a client and also to create a policy and and register it.

In my ExternalClient class, I am using the IHttpClientFactory to consume my client and IAsyncPolicy policy to wrap my calls with the policy I have created and set up on my Startup.

Startup.cs

```
...
services.AddHttpClients(Configuration);
services.AddRetryPolicy(Configuration);
...
```

ServiceCollectionExtension.cs

```
...
var policy = Policy
            .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryCount), (exception, timeSpan, count, 
context) =>
            {
                LogTo.Error($"Failed while posting to {myClient.Host}, retrying: " +
                            $"{count} of {retryCount} in " +
                            $"{timeSpan.TotalSeconds} seconds, with exception " +
                            $"{exception.Message}");
            });

            services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", c => { c.BaseAddress = new Uri(myClient.Host); })
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Credentials = credentialsCache
            });
...
```

ExternalClient

```
...
    try
    {
        var response = await _policy
            .ExecuteAsync(async () => (await _client.PostAsync(endpoint, requestBody)).EnsureSuccessStatusCode())
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogTo.Error(ex, "Unable to contact Myclient");
    }
...
```

The implementation of the policy works fine, the next step is to examine is there is a way to add a failover url for my client. I have checked the [documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory) for Polly and also have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201899/retry-http-request-from-net-with-different-proxy-server) approach with WebClient but this would work if the policy and the implementation are in the same place. I believe it would be possible to do it if I have the http client call happen in a method where I can wrap the call to that with ExecuteAsync and then supply diffent client but I was looking a more elegant solution, something that maybe out there but I am not aware of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Polly retry with different url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084405/polly-retry-with-different-url)

Answer (score 0):

As [covered in other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196052/), `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` is not designed for `BaseAddress` to be changed.

You do not however have to use different `HttpClient` instances to target URIs with different base addresses.  You can simply not set the `BaseAddress` property on the `HttpClient` you configure, and use fully-qualified URIs (to switch eg between primary and failover URIs) in the calls you place through a single `HttpClient` instance.