# Polly Retry URL duplicating values

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, polly, retry-logic

I have configured a Polly IAsyncPolicy using the following code:

```
IAsyncPolicy retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>(e => !e.IsBadRequest())
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(
        Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2("00:00:01", 5),
        onRetry: (response, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
    {
        if (!context.TryGetLogger(out var logger))
        {
            return;
        }

        logger.LogWarning($"Retrying call {retryCount} with timespan: {timeSpan} due to: {response.Message}");
    });
```

This is injected into the class as a Singleton and used in the following manner:

```
var context = new Context($"API-call-{Guid.NewGuid()}", new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "logger", _logger },
});

await _resiliencePolicy.ExecuteAsync(async ctx => await _apiClient.Post.Delete(2), _context);
```

The issue occurs when a retry is made, the original url https://someurl.com/post/2 now becomes https://someurl.com/post/22 (two is repeated) and this keeps happening for each retry. For say the 10th retry the URL would be https://someurl.com/post/222222222

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share with us what does `_apiClient.Post.Delete(2)` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition retry **re-executes** the provided user delegate / user callback. That means it does not alter anything on the request on your behalf.

For instance, if you want to change the request url in case of `HttpClient` request then you have to write a code which fetches the new url each time the user delegate is called by the retry policy. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084405/polly-retry-with-different-url/62086579#62086579) you can find an example.

So, the `_apiClient.Post.Delete(2)` **suspectedly** works in a way that it append the provided number at the end of the stored request url.

Some like this (pseudo-code):

```
this.RequestUrl = $"{this.RequestUrl}{deleteParameter}";
```

In order to fix that (*if you can change the underlying code*) you have to append the number to the base url to construct the request url (pseudo-code):

```
this.RequestUrl = $"{this.BaseUrl}{deleteParameter}";
```

Comment: That is exactly what was happening. The underlying code was appending the id to the existing Url. Thanks for your help